# Split a name and a (country) into two columns

Tags: r

I have data with the format below and I am trying to separate the name of the singer from the country using the 'separate' function; however, it separates the first names and last names into different columns as well. How can I separate the whoel name into 1 column and the country into another one? Could you guys please help me out with what I am doing incorrectly?

```
x1 <- tibble(singer=c("Katheryn Elizabeth Hudson (USA)","Taylor Swift (USA)","Dua Lipa (UK)","Jessie J (UK)"))
```

```
new_table <- x1 %>% 
  separate(singer, into=c("Singer_name", "Country", sep = '"()"))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use a regex lookaround to split at the space before the `(`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
x1 %>% 
    separate(singer, into=c("Singer_name", "Country"), sep = '\\s+(?=\\()')
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  Singer_name               Country
#  <chr>                     <chr>  
#1 Katheryn Elizabeth Hudson (USA)  
#2 Taylor Swift              (USA)  
#3 Dua Lipa                  (UK)   
#4 Jessie J                  (UK)
```

Or to remove the brackets

```
x1 %>% 
 separate(singer, into=c("Singer_name", "Country"), sep = '\\s\\(|\\)')
```

---

If we don't need the brackets, use `extract` to capture characters as a  group

```
x1 %>%
  extract(singer, into = c("Singer_name", "Country"),  "(.*)\\s\\(([^)]+).")
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  Singer_name               Country
#  <chr>                     <chr>  
#1 Katheryn Elizabeth Hudson USA    
#2 Taylor Swift              USA    
#3 Dua Lipa                  UK     
#4 Jessie J                  UK
```